# OpenPyXL no modifica valor columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

Estoy intentando modificar el contenido de las celdas de una columna. El contenido es una fórmula, tipo `=SUMA(A1;0;B1)`, no es el ejemplo real, pero es para hacerse una idea y reproducir mi problema.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import openpyxl as xl

wb = xl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")

sh = wb.active

filas = sh.max_row

for e in range(1, filas + 1):
   z = "F" + str(e)
   target = sh[z].value
   sh[z].value = target.replace(";0;", ";1;") 

wb.save("copy.xlsx")
```

Pero cuando voy a mirar que ***copy.xlsx*** tenga ese valor modificado, me encuentro con que tiene el anterior. ¿A qué puede deberse esto?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: @FJSevilla el contenido es una fórmula, tipo `sh[F1].value -> "=SUMA(A1;0;B1)"`. No es el ejemplo real, pero es para que te hagas una idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asegúrate que la cadena representativa de la fórmula del atributo `value` coincide con lo que esperas. Probando con un xlsx de ejemplo, para una celda con la fórmula:

> =SUMA(A1;0;B1)

el contenido de `value` es:

> '=SUM(A1,0,B1)'

Se reemplaza `;` por `,` al parsear, por lo que `str.replace` debería ser:

```
.replace(",0,", ",1,")
```

Por cierto, te complicas demasiado para iterar sobre la columna si usas versiones recientes de OpenPyXL:

```
import openpyxl as xl



wb = xl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
sh = wb.active

for cell in sh["F"]:
    cell.value = cell.value.replace(",0,", ",1,")

wb.save("copy.xlsx")
```

Comment: muchas gracias @FJSevilla, la verdad es que no sabía eso, así me quito de problemas. por otro lado, lo de las versiones recientes tampoco lo sabía, acabo de empezar hace poco con este módulo y estoy en pañales, como quien dice